# how to fix python error exeptional illegal instruction

Tags: python, error

Please help; I'm stressed as I have a project to pass and I can't open Blender. It says something like `Error: EXCEPTION_ILLEGAL_INSTRUCTION`.
Please just help me, I'm really stressed, so please understand my attitude. The screenshot is blurred because Blender closes after 1 sec so it's hard to screenshot it).

[image: Screenshot of the error]

Comment: did it work previously? Have you installed anything else that may have affected the Python setup of your windows machine? Have you tried reinstalling to a different folder? Can you install it as a different user? Have you tried rebooting?

Comment: Did you already tried the `.zip` version?

Comment: Which version of Windows 7 (32bit, 64bit)? All recent Updates installed?  Looks like Service Pack 1 is missing.

Comment: this is my answer guys for rob-yes i tried all bro.for brockman-im now installing the zip file and ill post the result here.for u metaphor im installing 64 bit .what do u mean by 1 service pack is missing?

Comment: guys.no matter how many times i install and uninstall it . it always says they is a script error in (the folder where i place blender) .

Comment: Related [https://developer.blender.org/T44851]  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/63128/my-blender-doesnt-startup-when-i-try-to-execute-it

Comment: If you need to reply to users you need to '@' them, e.g. @RayMairlot, otherwise they won't be notified of your comment.

Comment: @RayMairlot thank you .im new to this site so i dont know a thing yet

Comment: guys i installed 32 bit .somehow it worked even though my pc is 64 .anyways thank you guys very much  i love each and everyone of you im so happy <3